# Frame Rate issue Apple SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, frame-rate

I'm currently making an app for an assessment which generates a maze using Recursive Backtracking. It's a 25x25 grid maze, with each wall being a separate SKSpriteNode (I read up that using SKShapeNodes was not efficient).

However, there are about 1300 nodes in the scene, which is causing some frame rate issues, even on my iPhone X. It's currently idling at about 15-30 fps, which really isn't ideal.

Are there any ideas on how to either cache SKSpriteNodes to produce better performance? I'm probably overlooking many things, and not creating walls in the most efficient way but the frames seem way too low to be correct?

If anyone would be able to suggest or nudge me in the right location that would be a huge help.

Comment: This question is too broad, nobody will be able to provide you a real answer.  The iPhone is capable of rendering more than 1300 nodes, but without any context, people will not be able to tell you what is causing the bottleneck in your app.

Comment: try to keep your textures small in size as well (200, 200 if possible) also if they are png's try running them through TinyPNG.com to reduce the files size greatly. But I agree with Knight0fDragon unless you post examples of the images or screenshots or some code, no one will be able to pin point your issues

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I located an issue where there were nodes doubled up behind each other, and once they were removed the frames increased back to 60fps. I was originally creating SKSpriteNodes as plain red rectangles (with the inbuilt functions). I'm not entirely sure what the issue was other than the doubled up nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using [`SKTexture`s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktexture) for repeated, identical images. See [*Creating a Textured Sprite Node*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode#2647039).

For optimal performance, create sprites before compile time and put them in a texture atlas in your asset catalog. For creating texture atlases, see the documentation for [`SKTextureAtlas`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktextureatlas).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Does this apply to just plain coloured shapes? For example, if each sprite is just a red rectangle? If I was to create a red texture to apply to each sprite, will the performance increase?

Comment: If each sprite is literally just a red rectangle, just using a `SKSpriteNode` and setting the fill color would probably perform better. You could try this method too to compare. Either way, if you feel like this answer helped, be sure to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a go with it and see how it goes